# how to convert char to decimal in (sybase|sql server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sybase

how do you convert char to decimal of with precision 10, scale 5 in sybase or sqlserver stored proc?

i.e something like
exec Test @Test_Decimal=convert(decimal(10,5), '1.15')

Thanks

Comment: ANSI SQL's CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10,5))?

Comment: `select convert(decimal(10,5), '4343.5')`

Comment: i cant add @Test_Decimal=select convert(decimal(10,5), '4343.5')  to the stored proc exec statement. that producess incorrect syntax near keyword select. and i cant exec Test @Test_Decimal=convert(decimal(10,5), '4343.5') that produces incorrect syntax near keyword convert

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
declare @param decimal(10,5)
set @param = cast('1.15' as decimal(10,5))
exec Test @param
```

Comment: sorry i should have been more clear, i cant make a change to the stored proc. so i need to convert from the exec command using the convert function. this doesnt work for my use case.

Comment: You don't need to make change to stored proc. You only need to make change to the way you call stored proc. You can not use any function as a parameter to the stored proc.